# C# Error Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Tags: c#, player.io

C#
Hey I'm trying to do a OR statement for my gift code system like kota or jojo123 or example123 so i can have multiple codes without multiple if and else statements but i try || and i get this error

Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

```
playerDB.Key != playerDB.GetString("sc-ehgdtih" || playerDB.GetString("sc-kota123")))
```

Comment: can you show us the code? Also the error explains it completely `if("foo" || "bar")` that does not work! Because they are strings, and you can't compaire 2 strings using the `||` or `&&` operators.

Comment: Hi, if happy, can you accept my ans to close this question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The conditional operator || must be applied to boolean expressions, so you can do

```
if ( a == "123" || a == "456")
```

Comment: The second one is an assignment, and will give a similar error (bool and string).

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is

```
playerDB.Key != playerDB.GetString("sc-ehgdtih") || playerDB.Key != playerDB.GetString("sc-kota123")
```

A common mistake is to assume you can do something like

```
if(a == "1" || "2")
```

When you actually have to specify the complete comparison each time

```
if(a == "1" || a == "2")
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are misplaced a parathesis, and in addition you were comparing one thing only. This should do what you need, and slightly prettier.

```
if (!playerDB.Key.in(
        new [] { playerDB.GetString("sc-ehgdtih"), playerDB.GetString("sc-kota123") }))
```